# How can i access QueryString values in Serializer Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to access querystring values in serializer class.

```
class OneZeroSerializer(rest_serializer.ModelSerializer):

    location = rest_serializer.SerializerMethodField('get_alternate_name')

    def get_alternate_name(self, obj):
        view = self.context['view']
        print view.kwargs['q']  #output is {}
        return 'foo'


    class Meta:
        model = OneZero

        fields = ('id', 'location')
```

**Views**

```
class OneZeroViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

   serializer_class = OneZeroSerializer

   queryset = OneZero.objects.all()
```

Is this right way to access querystring?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When using ViewSets, you can access the request in the serializer context (like you access the view). You can access the query params from this

```
def get_alternate_name(self, obj):
    request = self.context['request']
    print request.query_params['q']
    return 'foo'
```

The attribute view.kwargs contains the named arguments parsed from your url-config, so from the path-part.

Comment: For newer versions: `request.QUERY_PARAMS` has been deprecated in favor of `request.query_params` since version 3.0, and has been fully removed as of version 3.2.

Comment: I would suggest using `request.query_params.get('q')` so it won't raise an exception.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests#query_params) you want to use `self.request.query_params`

You can see it being used [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#filtering-against-query-parameters)

***DEPRECATED:***

Prior to DRF 3.0:

> The usage of `request.QUERY_PARAMS` is used and not the lowercased `request.query_params`

Comment: This is the error when i printed this command 'OneZeroSerializer' object has no attribute 'request'. I think this can be use in viewset not for Serializer Class

Comment: Ah yes, misread what was going on.  Serializers aren't tied to requests, you can use them separately if you so chose.  These means they have no concept of GET and POST data.  You need to modify your view to send the query params to the serializer.

Answer (score 5):

`self.context['request'].query_params`