# How to properly access data using request.query_params?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to access data from the get request that is being sent while this post request can be sent.
This is what my create method looks like inside the serializer that I am using for this post request:

```
  def create(self, validated_data):
    """Create and return a new tagging"""

    user = None
    request = self.context.get("request")
    if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
      user = request.user

    score = 0
    tag_data = validated_data.pop('tag', None)
    if tag_data:
      tag = Tag.objects.get_or_create(**tag_data)[0]
      validated_data['tag'] = tag
      if not Tag.objects.all().filter(name=tag.name).exists():
        score = 0
      elif Tag.objects.all().filter(name=tag.name).exists():
        score += 5

    tagging = Tagging(
      user=user,
      gameround=validated_data.get("gameround"),
      # resource=request.query_params['resource'],
      # resource=validated_data.get("resource"),
      resource=request.query_params.get('resource'),
      tag=validated_data.get("tag"),
      created=datetime.now(),
      score=score,
      origin=""
    )
    tagging.save()
    return tagging
```

This is the problematic line:

```
resource=request.query_params.get('resource')
```

I am getting an AttributeError "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'query_params'"

Am I using query_params.get() the wrong way or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing request object and that is not present in your serializer.

You can access request that is present inside serializer context

```
request = self.context['request']

...

# Now you can use request
resource=request.query_params.get('resource')
```

For more info look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23015710/12845003)